# MySQL Multiple interests matching problem

Tags: mysql, loops, for-loop

I have a database where users enter their interests. I want to find people with matching interests.

The structure of the interest table is

`interestid | username | hobby | location | level | matchinginterestids`

Let's take two users to keep it simple.

- User Joe may have 10 different interest records
- User greg may have 10 different interest records.

I want to do the following algorithm

- Take Joe's interest record 1 and look for matching hobbies and locations from the interest database. Put any matching interest id's in the matches field. Then go to joe's interest record 2 etc..

I guess what I need is some sort of for loop that will loop through all of joe's intersts and then do an update each time it finds a match in the interest database. Is that even possible in MySQL?

---

Further example:

I am Dan. I have 3 interests. Each interest is composed of 3 subjects:

- Dan cats,nutrition,hair
- Dan superlens,dna,microscopes
- Dan film,slowmotion,fightscenes

Other people may have other interests

#### Joe:

- Joe cats,nutrition,strength
- Joe superlens,dna,microscopes

#### Moe

- Moe mysql,queries,php
- Moe film,specialfx,cameras
- Moe superlens,dna,microscopes

Now I want the query to return the following when I log in as Dan:

Here are your interest matches:

--- is interested in cats nutrition hair
Joe is interested in cats and nutrition
Joe and Moe are interested in superlens, dna, microscopes
Moe is interested in film

The query needs to iterate through all Dan's interests, and compare 3,2,1 subject matches.

I could do this in php from a loop but it would be calling the database all the time to get the results.  I was wondering if there's a crafty way to do it using a single query Or maybe 3 separate queries one looking for 3 matches, one for 2 and one for 1.

Comment: See also repeat question [SO 5925321](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925321/interest-matching-puzzle-using-mysql).

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely possible with MySQL, but I think you may be going about it in an awkward way. I would begin by structuring the tables as follows:

```
TABLE Users ( userId, username, location )
TABLE Interests( interestId, hobby )
TABLE UserInterests( userId, interestId, level )
```

When a user adds an interest, if it hasn't been added before, you add it to the `Interests` table, and then add it to the `UserInterests` table. When you want to check for other nearby folks with similar interests, you can simply query the `UserInterests` table for other people who have similar interests, which has all that information for you already:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId
  FROM UserInterests
  WHERE interestId IN (
     SELECT interestId
       FROM UserInterests
       WHERE userId = $JoesID
     )
```

This can probably be done in a more elegant fashion without subqueries, but it's what I thought of now.

Comment: +1 for the sensible schema.  This query should be more efficient: SELECT otherpeople.userid
FROM UserInterests
JOIN UserInterests AS OtherPeoplesInterests ON OtherPeoplesInterests.interestId = UserInterests.interestId AND OtherPeoplesInterests.userId != UserInterests.userId
WHERE UserInterests.userId = [Joe's user ID]

Comment: @tehshrike - Looks interesting, good use of joins. How would the `otherpeople.userid` work, though? What does `otherpeople` reference in that context?

Comment: @eykanal Oh hey, that was a mistake.  It should be `SELECT OtherPeoplesInterests.userId` :-)

Comment: I don't think this will work for what I really want to do.  I wanted to have each interest be composed of 3 fields which are subjects like cats,nutrition,shampoo, or rockets,mars,thrusters.   I also want them to be able to search for 1,2 or 3 subject matches. So maybe ideally you can find someone who also wants to develop rocket thrusters to mars, but maybe that doesn't exist but there's someone who wants to develop rocket thrusters to the moon etc...So I have 10 interests and I want to take interest 1 and find all 3 subject matches, then 2 then 1. Does that work with this schema.

Comment: @daniel - Let me put it this way: any good database schema will never repeat data. The way you have it now, the same interests will be repeated numerous times in the `interest` table. So, you can modify the schema I suggested to allow numerous hobbies per row in the interests table, or you can come up with a smarter search algorithm that the one I provided. I would argue that either way is more efficient, fro a database design standpoint, that the original schema you posted.

Comment: I'm still stuck...the schema may not work if one person has an interest of dogs,grooming,brushes and another person has an interst of

Answer (score 4):

As per special request from daniel, although it's kind of duplicate but never mind.

**The schema explained**

```
TABLE User (id, username, location )
TABLE Interests(id, hobby )
TABLE UserInterest(userId, interestId, level )
```

Table `users` has just user data and a primary key field at the start: `id`.
The primary key field is a pure link field, the other fields are info fields.

Table `Interest` again has a primary key that is use to link against and some info field
*(ehm well just one, but that's because this is an example)*

Note that `users` and `interests` are not linked in any way whatsoever.
That's odd, why is that?
Well there is a problem... One `user` can have multiple `intrests` **and** `intrests` can belong to multiple `people`. 
We can solve this by changing to users table like so:

```
TABLE users (id, username, location, intrest1, intrest2, intrest3)
```

**But this is a bad, really really bad idea**, because:

1. This way only 3 interests per user are allowed
2. It's a waste of space if many users have 2, 1 or no interests
3. And most important, it makes queries difficult to write.

Example query for linking with the **bad** users table

```
SELECT * FROM user
INNER JOIN interests ON (user.intrest1 = interests.id) or
                        (user.intrest2 = interests.id) or
                        (user.intrest3 = interests.id);
```

And that's just for a simple query listing all users and their interests.
It quickly gets horribly complex as things progress.

**many-to-many relationships**

The solution to the problem of a many to many relationship is to use a link table.
This reduces the many-to-many relationship into two 1-to-many relationships.

A: 1 `userinterest` to many `user`'s
B: 1 `userinterest` to many `interests`

Example query using a link-table

```
SELECT * FROM user
INNER JOIN userInterest ON (user.id = userInterest.userID)  //many-to-1
INNER JOIN interest ON (interest.id = userInterest.InterestID); //many-to-1
```

**Why is this better?**

1. Unlimited number of interests per user and visa versa
2. No wasted space if a user has a boring life and few if any interests
3. Queries are simpler to maintain

**Making it interesting**

Just listing all users is not very fun, because then we still have to process the data in php or whatever. But there's no need to do that SQL is a query language after all so let's ask a question:

> **Give all users that share an interest with user Moe.**

OK, lets make a cookbook and gather our ingredients. What do we need.

Well we have a `user` "Moe" and we have other `user`'s, everybody but **not** "Moe".
And we have the interests shared between them.
And we'll need the link table `userInterest` as well because that's the way we link `user` and `interests`.

Let's first list all of Moe's Hobbies

```
SELECT i_Moe.hobby FROM interests AS i_Moe
INNER JOIN userInterests as ui2 ON (ui2.InterestID = i_Moe.id)
INNER JOIN user AS u_Moe ON (u_Moe.id = ui2.UserID)
WHERE u_Moe.username = 'Moe';
```

Now we combine the select for all users against only Moe's hobbies.

```
SELECT u_Others.username FROM interests AS i_Others
INNER JOIN userinterests AS ui1 ON (ui1.interestID = i_Others.id)
INNER JOIN user AS u_Others ON (ui1.user_id = u_Others.id)
/*up to this point this query is a list of all interests of all users*/

INNER JOIN Interests AS i_Moe ON (i_Moe.Hobby = i_Others.hobby)
/*Here we link Moe's hobbies to other people's hobbies*/

INNER JOIN userInterests as ui2 ON (ui2.InterestID = i_Moe.id)
INNER JOIN user AS u_Moe ON (u_Moe.id = ui2.UserID)
/*And using the link table we link Moe's hobbies to Moe*/

WHERE u_Moe.username = 'Moe'
/*We limited user-u_moe to only 'Moe'*/

AND u_Others.username <> 'Moe';
/*and the rest to everybody except 'Moe'*/
```

Because we are using `INNER JOIN`'s on link fields only matches will be considered and non-matches will be thrown out.
If you read the query in english it goes like this.

Consider all users who are not `Moe`, call them `U_others`.
Consider user `Moe`, call him U_Moe.
Consider user `Moe`'s Hobbies, call those `i_Moe`
Consider other users's Hobbies, call those `i_Others`
**Now link `i_Others` hobbies to `u_Moe`'s Hobbies**
Return only users from `U_Others` that have a hobby that matches Moe's

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Good explanation, this could be a blog post explaining many-to-many relationships.

Comment: I rebuilt everything with this schema to play with, but I get an error around SELECT u_Others.username FROM interests AS i_Others. Where does  u_Others.username get defined. Somewhere is it supposed to define that u_others is every user but moe?

Comment: @daniel; `INNER JOIN user AS u_Others ON (ui1.user_id = u_Others.id)` + `AND u_Others.username <> 'Moe'`.

Comment: Working now thanks. How come I can only comment from the computer that I posted the question on? StackOverflow is ultra quirky

Comment: @johan I got it working with 1,2 or 3 interests. I'm confused at the end I want to list not only the username of the matching interest but also the interest subjects.  I want to say dan shares your interest of mysql,programming,and stackoverflow, or dan shares your interests in cats.  What part of the query determines the final output. Would I do another join. Confused...

Comment: I think I got it. I just needed to SELECT things from the already joined tables by their aliases... Now instead of Selecting u_Others.username only I Select u_Others.username,i_Others.subject1.  This is very cool and I think I'm getting the hang of it. I'll have to double check though to see if it's doing what I think it's doing. Thanks.

Comment: @daniel savage, I think you're getting the hang of it, I personally learned a lot from seeing questions on SO, trying to solve them and then have look at the answers to see if I got it right.