# can couchdb do loops

Tags: mysql, loops, for-loop, couchdb

Can couchdb do loops?

Let's say I have a database of interests that have 3 fields
subject1,subject2,subject3. example, cats,nutrition,hair or space,telescopes,optics etc.

A person (A) has 10 interests composed of 3 fields each.

10 more people B,C,D...have 10 interests each composed of 3 subjects each.

When person A logs in I want the system to search for all people with matching interests.

In javascript I would normally loop through all the interests and then find matching ones I guess using
two loops. Then store the matches in another database for the user like "matchinginterests".

Is there any easy way to do this in couchdb compared to mysql -- which seems very complicated.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Databases don't do for loops, unless you're talking about a stored procedure which you're not. In this case you're having javascript do the looping. Unless you're planning on changing languages, yes you'll still have for loops.

Comment: Couchdb isn't mysql. YOu should be able to write one in hte javascript terminal for couchdb.

Comment: I think [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227587/how-to-match-a-superset-key-to-a-subset-using-group-level-sub-selects-in-couchdb/5256801#5256801) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5227587/453605) can be useful to you.

Answer (score 5):

I think I understand what you are asking. The answer is pretty straightforward with Map/Reduce.

Say you have the following people documents:

```
{
   "name": "Person A",
   "interests" [ "computers", "fishing", "sports" ]
}
{
   "name": "Person B",
   "interests" [ "computers", "gaming" ]
}
{
   "name": "Person C",
   "interests" [ "hiking", "sports" ]
}
{
   "name": "Person D",
   "interests" [ "gaming" ]
}
```

You would probably want to emit your key as the interest, with the value as the person's name (or `_id`).

```
function (doc) {
   for (var x = 0, len = doc.interests.length; x < len; x++) {
      emit(doc.interests[x], doc..name);
   }
}
```

Your view results would look like this:

- computers => Person A
- computers => Person B
- fishing => Person A
- gaming => Person B
- gaming => Person D
- hiking => Person C
- sports => Person A
- sports => Person C

To get a list of people with computers as an interest, you can simply send `key="computers"` as part of the query string.

If you want to add a reduce function to your map, you can simply use `_count` (shortcut to use a compiled reduce function) and you can retrieve a count of all the people with a particular interest, you can even use that to limit which interests you query to build your relationships.

Comment: Let's say an interest is defined by 3 subjects for example

Comment: Let's say an interest is defined by 3 words for example: cat,nutrition,hair or rockets,mars,propulsion.   I want to search for other folks with the same 3 word interests. I may have 20 3 word interests.  The goal here is to take interest1 of mine, then searches for matches, then interest 2, then searches for matches.  In mysql this is really complicated. Can couchdb do the same task more easily that mysql. If I were building it in javascript it would simply be a loop inside another loop. But mysql does not have loops -- so I'm told. It has different mechanisms which I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really following you... Are the interests always in the same groups of 3? If so, then just emit the 3 items as the key (sorted alphabetically and lowercase to make it easy to match)

Answer (score 0):

> When person A logs in I want the system to search for all people with matching interests.

```
SELECT i_them.* FROM interests AS i_me
INNER JOIN interests AS i_them ON (i_them.person != i_me.person) AND
 ((i_them.subject1 IN (i_me.subject1, i_me.subject2, i_me.subject3)) OR
  (i_them.subject2 IN (i_me.subject1, i_me.subject2, i_me.subject3)) OR 
  (i_them.subject3 IN (i_me.subject1, i_me.subject2, i_me.subject3)))
WHERE i_me.person = 'A'
```

Is that what you wanted to do?

If you design your tables a little smarter though you'd do it like

```
SELECT DISTINCT them.* FROM person AS me
INNER JOIN interest AS i_me ON (i_me.person_id = me.id)
INNER JOIN interest AS i_them ON (i_them.subject = i_me.subject)
INNER JOIN person AS them ON (them.id = i_them.person.id AND them.id != me.id)
WHERE me.name = 'A'
```

Using the following tables

```
table interest
  id integer primary key autoincrement
  person_id integer //links to person table
  subject varchar //one subject per row.
  +-----+-----------+---------+
  | id  | person_id | subject |
  +-----+-----------+---------+
  | 1   | 3         | cat     |
  | 2   | 3         | stars   |
  | 3   | 3         | eminem  |
  | 4   | 1         | cat     |
  | 5   | 1         | dog     |
  | 6   | 2         | dog     |
  | 7   | 2         | cat     | 

table person
  id integer primary key autoincrement
  name varchar
  address varchar
  +-----+------+---------+
  | id  | name | address |
  +-----+------+---------+
  | 1   | A    | here    |
  | 2   | Bill | there   |
  | 3   | Bob  | everyw  |

result
+-----+------+---------+
| id  | name | address |
+-----+------+---------+
| 2   | Bill | there   |
| 3   | Bob  | everyw  |
```

This is how (what you call) 'looping' in SQL works...

First you take person with name 'A' from the table.

```
me.id me.name me.address
| 1   | A    | here    |
```

You look up all the interests

```
me.id me.name me.address i_me.subject
| 1   | A    | here      | cat
| 1   | A    | here      | dog
```

Then you match everyone elses interests

```
me.id me.name me.address i_me.subject i_them.subject i_them.person_id
| 1   | A    | here      | cat        | cat          | 3
| 1   | A    | here      | cat        | cat          | 2
| 1   | A    | here      | dog        | dog          | 2
```

And then you match the person to them's interest (except for me of course)

```
me.id me.name me.address i_me.subject i_them.subject i_them.person_id them.name
| 1   | A    | here      | cat        | cat          | 3              | Bob 
| 1   | A    | here      | cat        | cat          | 2              | Bill 
| 1   | A    | here      | dog        | dog          | 2              | Bill
```

Then you return only the data from `them` and 'throw' the rest away, and remove duplicate rows `DISTINCT`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is an excellent example for a single subject. I'm confused about how I would do it if an "interest" is actually composed of 3 subjects like cat,nutrition,shampoo or mars,explorer,device. Ideally I'd like to match 1,2, or 3 subjects. I'd like to compare the mysql version vs the couchdb version. I can go either way. I've used both but at a beginner level.

Comment: @Daniel, if you add more interests and more people, the exact same query will do the work, try it out for yourself.

Comment: I duplicated the database on my local system but can't duplicate the query to test it. I don't understand your references eg. i_them, i_me, them.* It would really help me to have an example query that uses the tables and info in the tables you provided rather than the references so I can try it. I really want to try this and play with it so I can learn more.

Comment: @daniel savage, I_me is an alias for my `interests`, i_them is an alias for other peoples `interests`. Because I'm joining table `interests` with itself, I need an alias, otherwise MySQL cannot see the difference between them. Same for me: alias for my `person`, them = alias for other peoples `person`. I do a self join on that as well.

Comment: Sorry for being dense, but I'm still not understanding. I thought you had to use AS to make an alias in mysql.  How does mysql know what your aliases mean, where are they defined? Will this work if I paste it in to phpmyadmin's mysql box? If not what do I have to do to get the example working?  I have a limited understanding of mysql right now -- just the basics, but I do have a couple of good books.

Comment: `as` is optional, I've rewritten the queries with as, but you can always leave `as` out in MySQL.

Comment: Okay I got now. Thanks it actually works. I modified the query so it would work for matching 1 or more interests, 2 or more interests and all 3. I'm a little worried that I'm violating some database principle.  Can you comment on this other schema and solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906346/mysql-multiple-interests-matching-problem