# indexing a PouchDB db by the keys of an array of obj

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have data in PouchDB that looks like so, about 200K of such records

```
{
    "title": "blah blah blah",
    "authors": [
        { "name": "Fudd, Elmer"},
        { "name": "Duck, D."},
        { "name": "Walker, Diana"},
        { "name": "Washington, Grg,"}
    ],
    "description": "The annals"
}
```

I want to be able query authors

```
db.find({
    "selector": {
        "authors.name": {
        "$regex": "^Wa"
        }
    },
    "fields": ["_id", "title", "authors"]
}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }

    console.log(result);
});
```

The thing is, I just can't figure out how to make an index on authors. I've tried many variations, including

```
const docsByAuthorName = function(doc) {
    for (let element of doc.creators) {
        emit(element.name, element);
    }
};

let idx = {
    fields: [{
        "name": { "map": docsByCreatorName }
    }],
    ddoc: "authors",
    name: "name",
    type: "json"
};

db.createIndex({
    index: idx
}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }

    console.log(result)
});
```

But I continue to get the message that there is no index and that I should index my db to improve query timings. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** I discovered a post on [secondary indexes](https://pouchdb.com/2014/05/01/secondary-indexes-have-landed-in-pouchdb.html) and followed the instructions there

```
let idx = {
    _id: '_design/authorsByName',
    views: {
        'authorsByName': {
            map: function(doc) {
                for (let element of doc.creators) {
                    emit(element.name); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

db.put(idx).then(function (info) {
    // design doc created
}).catch(function (err) {
     // if err.name === 'conflict', then
     // design doc already exists
});
```

When I run the query, I get the following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token for
    … <snip> …
The user's map/reduce function threw an uncaught error.
You can debug this error by doing:
myDatabase.on('error', function (err) { debugger; });
Please double-check your map/reduce function.
evalmachine.<anonymous>:34
};var log = function () {};var isArray = Array.isArray;var toJSON = JSON.parse;var __emitteds__ = [];var emit = function (key, value) {__emitteds__.push([key, value]);};var __result__ = (for (let element of doc.creators) {
                                                                                                                                                                                           ^^^
```

So, now I am not sure if I can put regular JS in a PouchDB `map` function

Answer (score 0):

In you *updated* map function, make the following changes:

```
//for (let element of doc.creators) {
for(var i=0, length=doc.creators.length; i<length; i++){
    //emit(element.name);
    emit(doc.creators[i], doc.title);
}
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49610717/3405291) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5917451/3405291).