# Indexing Pouch db multi dimensional documents

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

Looking for a way to index pouchDB

Can't find a way to index when i have multiple dimensions

Here is my document client example

Note that client may have a few invoice

```
{
    clientId : 2
    clientName : 'toto'
    phoneNumber : '2342342'
    invoices : [
        {
            invoiceNumber : '12312313' , 
            Amount : 234242, 
            barCode : '1234324', 
        },  
        {
            invoiceNumber : '12312313' , 
            Amount : 234242, 
            barCode : '1234324', 
        }
    ]
}
{
    clientId : 3
    clientName : 'tata'
    phoneNumber : '2342342'
    invoices : [
        {
            invoiceNumber : '3542435' , 
            Amount : 234242, 
            barCode : '1234324', 
        },  
        {
            invoiceNumber : '235423' , 
            Amount : 234242, 
            barCode : '23454235', 
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to find clients by invoice number and barCode number

So indexing those are important

Thanks for your help

I have looked  at https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_index 
and https://pouchdb.com/2014/05/01/secondary-indexes-have-landed-in-pouchdb.html

So far not much luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on [CouchDB documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/intro.html):

> ... the `emit()` function can be called **multiple times** in the map function to create multiple entries in the view results from a single document...

---

Now we are going to use `emit()` multiple times in the map function. Also we are going to emit **arrays** to have both `invoiceNumber` and `barCode` as the index, like this:

```
var myIndex = {
    _id: '_design/my_index',
    views: {
        'my_index': {
            map: function (doc) {
                for(var i=0, length=doc.invoices.length; i<length; i++){
                    emit(
                        // emit array of invoiceNumber and barCode as key:
                        [doc.invoices[i].invoiceNumber, doc.invoices[i].barCode],
                        // emit array of clientId and clientName as value
                        // Actually, value can be whatever you want:
                        [doc.clientId, doc.clientName]
                    );
                }
            }.toString()
        }
    }
};
```

Now lets `PUT` our above design document and query it with PouchDB:

```
pouch.put(myIndex).then(() => {
  // query the index
  return pouch.query('my_index', {key: ['12312313','1234324']});
}).then(result => {
  // found docs with invoiceNumber === '12312313' and barCode === '1234324'
  console.log('Result: ', result)
});
```

---

Also take a look at [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5917451/3405291).