# Query/ Filter a attribute of type array in PoucheDB/ Hoodie JS

Tags: filter, nosql, store, pouchdb, hoodie

I am new in the NoSql / Hoodie JS / PouchDB stuff and so I try to find the best (most efficient way) to handle my data. I try to store some "employee" data and their vacations. Something like this:

```
{
    firstName: "Test",
    lastName: "User",
    vacations:  [
                    {start:"2018/03/02", end:"2018/03/03"},
                    {start:"2018/04/04", end:"2018/04/05"},
                    ...
                ]
}
```

So my employee is a "document" in terms of NoSql but the vacationlist give me some headaches because I think this list will grow but most of the time I will only need the data of the current week or month.

So my thoughts:

- Is it possible to create a view or query that returns the employees and only vacation items of the current month or year?
- Or should I just query everything and filter later in the UI?
- Or is this data design a bad idea and would end in any case in a nightmare.

What would you recommend?
Thank you very much and kind regards.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49610717/3405291 "Indexing Pouch db multi dimensional documents
")  or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5917451/3405291 "can couchdb do loops
") may help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to accomplish taht. What I  would normally do in your case:
- create a document type for employee (as you did) and another to vacation, where the vacation document has employee id. 
option a: in the employee you can keep an array of vacations, but in this case, you will have to updated it accordingly.
option b: you can create a view of all vacations by id. I would prefer this.